# DSMR P1 Frame example

Tags: c

I am reading DSMR P1 documentation and I have some doubts.
Documentation: https://www.netbeheernederland.nl/_upload/Files/Slimme_meter_15_a727fce1f1.pdf

This document gives an example of a P1 frame:

```
/ISk5\2MT382-1000
1-3:0.2.8(50)
0-0:1.0.0(101209113020W)
0-0:96.1.1(4B384547303034303436333935353037)
1-0:1.8.1(123456.789*kWh)
1-0:1.8.2(123456.789*kWh)
1-0:2.8.1(123456.789*kWh)
1-0:2.8.2(123456.789*kWh)
0-0:96.14.0(0002)
1-0:1.7.0(01.193*kW)
1-0:2.7.0(00.000*kW)
0-0:96.7.21(00004)
0-0:96.7.9(00002)
1-0:99.97.0(2)(0-0:96.7.19)(101208152415W)(0000000240*s)(101208151004W)(0000000301*s)
1-0:32.32.0(00002)
1-0:52.32.0(00001)
1-0:72.32.0(00000)
1-0:32.36.0(00000)
1-0:52.36.0(00003)
1-0:72.36.0(00000)
0-
0:96.13.0(303132333435363738393A3B3C3D3E3F303132333435363738393A3B3C3D3E3F303132333435363738393A3B3C
3D3E3F303132333435363738393A3B3C3D3E3F303132333435363738393A3B3C3D3E3F)
1-0:32.7.0(220.1*V)
1-0:52.7.0(220.2*V)
1-0:72.7.0(220.3*V)
1-0:31.7.0(001*A)
1-0:51.7.0(002*A)
1-0:71.7.0(003*A)
1-0:21.7.0(01.111*kW)
1-0:41.7.0(02.222*kW)
1-0:61.7.0(03.333*kW)
1-0:22.7.0(04.444*kW)
1-0:42.7.0(05.555*kW)
1-0:62.7.0(06.666*kW)
0-1:24.1.0(003)
0-1:96.1.0(3232323241424344313233343536373839)
0-1:24.2.1(101209112500W)(12785.123*m3)
!EF2F
```

I have a problem with several objects. For example, object 1-3: 0.2.8 is described as an alphanumeric string.
[object 1-3: 0.2.8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rR2Y.png)

According to the description in the documentation, the object should be sent as asciihex and in the example it looks like visible-string.
[octet-string description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zO5Y6.png)
[octet-string description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Bux1.png)

Can anyone tell me what's going on ?

Answer (score 0):

"50" is a valid asciihex string, and represents the value 80 in decimal. However apparently the hexadecimal value is used as the value (in this case meaning version 5.0). An earlier standards version was 4.2 and was represented as the string "42".

Don't get too confused about that, just understand that a asciihex string of "AB" means version A.B.